# VHDL equivalent of Verilog's Event Type and Event trigger ->event_a;

Tags: vhdl, verilog

How can I write the following code in VHDL??

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module tb;

  event event_a;

  initial begin
    #20  ->event_a;
    #30  ->event_a;
    #90  ->event_a;

    #100;
    $stop;
  end


always @(event_a) begin
    $display("hello word (%t)");
end

endmodule
```

HERE's WHAT I HAVE TRIED IN VHDL SO FAR:

```
library STD;
library IEEE;              
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use STD.textio.all;         
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;    

-- VHDL PSEUDO-CODE FOR WHAT I WANT TO DO IN VHDL INSTEAD OF VERILOG
entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb is
   event_a : event_type;   -- HOW TO DO THIS IN VHDL???
begin

    process
    begin
         ->event_a after 20 ns;  -- HOW TO DO THIS IN VHDL???
         ->event_a after 30 ns;
         ->event_a after 90 ns;
  
         wait; --Wait until simulation finishes
    end process;

    process(event_a)   -- HOW TO DO THIS IN VHDL???
        variable L : line;
    begin
        write(L, string'("hello");
        WriteLine(L, output);
    end process;

end architecture;

-- BEEEP: SYNTAX ERROR BECAUSE WRONG SYNTAX...
```

Comment: VHDL uses an event driven simulator where signal updates resulting a change in value cause events. IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update "If updating a signal causes the current value of that signal to change, then an *event* is said to have occurred on the signal,..." Processes resume execution in response to events. [One way to emulate a Verilog event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6aFZ.jpg).

Comment: So basically, you need to just keep inverting the value of a signal when ever you want to trigger an event...   sig <= !sig;  not as nice as Verilog, but functional.

Comment: Some signal whose value changes.

Answer (score 3):

There is no construct in VHDL equivalent to a Verilog event. However, VHDL does have a built-in *signal attribute* which enables one to emulate Verilog events. This attribute is `'transaction`; it is a signal that toggles every time an assignment is made to the signal (whether the assignment changes the value of the signal or not).

So, declare a signal (of any type you like) in the normal way:

```
signal event_a : boolean := true;
```

(You don't particularly need to initialise it.) Then, every time you want to emulate the Verilog `->` operator, you can drive some value (any value) onto the signal:

```
event_a <= true;
```

Because `'transaction` is itself a signal (a so-called *implicit signal*) and because `'transaction` toggles, you can use it in a *sensitivity list*, eg:

```
process(event_a'transaction)
```

You could not bother with `'transaction` and just toggle the signal (creating an *event* on that signal, causing the `'event` signal attribute to be true). Using `'transaction` is a bit nicer though, because you don't have to keep track of the signal's value; you can just assign the same value every time.

---

By the way, I didn't use `after` in VHDL, because a *signal assignment* behaves much like a *non-blocking assignment* in Verilog. If I use `after` with no modification to the delay values, I'll trigger the process at 20, 30 and 90 ns, rather than at 20, 50 and 140 ns (which I think is what you are after). In other words, this:

```
wait for 20 ns; event_a <= true;
wait for 30 ns; event_a <= true;
wait for 90 ns; event_a <= true;
```

is like this

```
begin
  #20 -> event_a;
  #30 -> event_a;
  #90 -> event_a;
end
```

Whereas this:

```
event_a <= true after 20 ns;
event_a <= true after 30 ns;
event_a <= true after 90 ns;
```

will actually only trigger one (Verilog-style) event - one at 90ns. This is because when a line of code containing a signal assignment is executed, any events created by previous assignments to the same signal (which haven't yet been actioned) are overwritten by the events created by the latest signal assignment.

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/i7Z_

```
use STD.textio.all;         

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb is
   signal event_a : boolean  := true;   -- or any other type
begin

    process
    begin
         wait for 20 ns; event_a <= true; 
         wait for 30 ns; event_a <= true;
         wait for 90 ns; event_a <= true;
  
         wait; --Wait until simulation finishes
    end process;

    process(event_a'transaction) 
        variable L : line;
    begin
        write(L, string'("hello"));
        WriteLine(output, L);
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: You'll note one of the four `hello` outputs shows up at time = 0. This is due to initialization (IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.5.2) wherein each process is executed until suspending, here in the last implicit wait statement derived from the process sensitivity list. Processes suspend and resume in wait statements (10.2 Wait statement). Either qualify execution of sequential statements in the process with the simulation time or use an explicit wait statement in lieu of the process sensitivity list before those sequential statements, preventing execution at time 0.

Comment: `event_a <= true after 20 ns, true after 30 ns, true after 90 ns;` will work because the simulation time for the scheduled transaction is determined from the simulation time when the assignment statement is executed. 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement "The time component of the transaction is determined by the current time added to the value of the time expression in the waveform element."

Comment: `will actually only trigger one event - one at 90ns` No, you'll get three events. There's only one entry for any simulation time in the projected output waveform. There are in order and to different times. There's a missing space between the abstract literal and time unit in the physical literals preceding the quoted portion. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3  Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters "At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal." It's non portable and relies on (a) particular vendor(s).